# Slides Flickering when setting Splide slider to RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, splidejs

I'm really stuck on this I found two other posts about this but nothing has worked.

Basically I set the direction of my Splide slider to RTL and every-time it brings in the next set of slides they flicker in and out.

The slider is set to autoplay using the autoplay extension.

This is the URL https://prismfly.webflow.io/

Here's the code:

```html
const one = new Splide( '.splide', {
  type   : 'loop',
  drag   : false,
  autoWidth: true,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  pagination: false,
  arrows: false,
  pauseOnFocus: false,
  direction:"rtl",
  autoScroll: {
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    speed: 1.3,
  },
} );
```

Hoping someone else has experienced this before. Would love any help or suggestions, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi so to solve the flickering issue in splide js you have to add some custom css:

```css
.splide--track {
  Direction:rtl;
}
```

If this didn't work so find the class of the splide track and set direction to rtl

Also set the width of the splide container to 100%

Hope this solves ur issue.